Proper Angular Material V3 Theming
I am trying to create an example Angular 19 app with Angular Material v3 having the following features:

custom light and dark themes;
toggle theme at runtime;
use color variants for primary, warn and the like as with the old color directive (a proper way for doing this in V3 is welcome, I fear it will imply a lot more themes...).

I thus created a new Angular 19 app and added Angular Material via ng add @angular/material.  You can find a full repro repository at https://github.com/Myrmex/angular-theming. The relevant code is reported below:
 (1) For styles, I ensured that no prebuilt theme is included in styles in my angular.json file and wrote this styles.scss:
// styles.scss
@use "@angular/material" as mat;

@include mat.core();

// create color configurations for light and dark themes
$light-theme: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      theme-type: light,
      primary: mat.$blue-palette,
    ),
  )
);

$dark-theme: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      theme-type: dark,
      primary: mat.$blue-palette,
    ),
  )
);

// base styles
html {
  color-scheme: light dark;
}

// default (light) theme
:root,
html:not(.dark-theme) {
  @include mat.all-component-themes($light-theme);
  & {
    color-scheme: light;
  }
}

// dark theme styles
html.dark-theme {
  // @include mat.all-component-themes($dark-theme);
  @include mat.all-component-colors($dark-theme);
  & {
    color-scheme: dark;
  }
}

body {
  background: var(--mat-sys-surface);
  color: var(--mat-sys-on-surface);
}

@include mat.color-variants-backwards-compatibility($light-theme);
@include mat.color-variants-backwards-compatibility($dark-theme);

 (2) I then added a theme service for toggling themes:
// theme.service.ts
import { Injectable, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

const THEME_KEY = 'app-theme-preference';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ThemeService {
  private readonly _htmlElement?: HTMLHtmlElement;

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
    // ensure we only access document/window in browser environment
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this._htmlElement = document.documentElement as HTMLHtmlElement;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Initialize theme on app startup
   */
  public initializeTheme() {
    if (!isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) return;
    const savedTheme = this.getSavedTheme();
    const systemTheme = this.getSystemTheme();

    // Prefer saved theme, fall back to system theme
    const initialTheme = savedTheme || systemTheme;
    this.setTheme(initialTheme);

    // Listen for system theme changes
    const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
    mediaQuery.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
      if (!this.getSavedTheme()) {
        this.setTheme(e.matches ? 'dark' : 'light');
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Toggle between light and dark themes
   */
  public toggleTheme(): 'light' | 'dark' | null {
    if (!isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) return null;

    const currentTheme = this.getCurrentTheme();
    const newTheme = currentTheme === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark';
    this.setTheme(newTheme);
    return newTheme;
  }

  /**
   * Set a specific theme.
   * @param theme 'light' or 'dark'.
   */
  public setTheme(theme: 'light' | 'dark') {
    if (!isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) return;

    console.log('Setting theme:', theme);

    // Save theme preference
    localStorage.setItem(THEME_KEY, theme);

    // Set color-scheme on html element
    this._htmlElement?.setAttribute('color-scheme', theme);

    // Toggle theme-specific classes
    if (theme === 'dark') {
      console.log('Adding dark-theme class');
      this._htmlElement?.classList.add('dark-theme');
      this._htmlElement?.classList.remove('light-theme');
    } else {
      console.log('Adding light-theme class');
      this._htmlElement?.classList.add('light-theme');
      this._htmlElement?.classList.remove('dark-theme');
    }
  }
  /**
   * Get the current active theme
   * @returns 'light' or 'dark'.
   */
  public getCurrentTheme(): 'light' | 'dark' {
    if (!isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) return 'light';

    return this._htmlElement?.getAttribute('color-scheme') as 'light' | 'dark';
  }

  private getSystemTheme(): 'light' | 'dark' {
    return window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches
      ? 'dark'
      : 'light';
  }

  /**
   * Get saved theme preference from localStorage
   * @returns Saved theme or null.
   */
  private getSavedTheme(): 'light' | 'dark' | null {
    if (!isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) return null;

    const savedTheme = localStorage.getItem(THEME_KEY);
    return savedTheme === 'light' || savedTheme === 'dark' ? savedTheme : null;
  }

  /**
   * Set theme based on system preference
   */
  public setThemeFromSystemPreference() {
    if (!isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) return;

    const prefersDarkScheme = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
    const initialTheme = prefersDarkScheme.matches ? 'dark' : 'light';
    this.setTheme(initialTheme);

    // Use addEventListener instead of deprecated addListener
    prefersDarkScheme.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
      // Only change if no saved preference exists
      if (!this.getSavedTheme()) {
        this.setTheme(e.matches ? 'dark' : 'light');
      }
    });
  }
}

 (3) Finally, I added a toggler component:
// theme-toggle.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

import { ThemeService } from '../../services/theme.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-theme-toggle',
  imports: [MatButtonModule, MatIconModule],
  templateUrl: './theme-toggle.component.html',
  styleUrl: './theme-toggle.component.scss',
})
export class ThemeToggleComponent implements OnInit {
  isDarkMode = false;

  constructor(private themeService: ThemeService) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.themeService.initializeTheme();
    // set initial theme
    this.updateThemeMode();
  }

  public toggleTheme() {
    this.themeService.toggleTheme();
    this.updateThemeMode();
  }

  private updateThemeMode() {
    this.isDarkMode = this.themeService.getCurrentTheme() === 'dark';
  }
}

with its HTML template:
<!-- theme-toggle.component.html -->
<button
  type="button"
  mat-icon-button
  (click)="toggleTheme()"
  aria-label="Toggle theme"
>
  <mat-icon>{{ isDarkMode ? "light_mode" : "dark_mode" }}</mat-icon>
</button>

 This works, but I have some glitches:

it seems that the default typography is not applied. Except when text is inside a button or other Material components, text appears with the default (Times New Roman) font and size, e.g. if I place a p element inside a mat-card. I tried to add typography via its simple font name, Roboto, by adding typography: Roboto as specified in the current theming guide; still, I get a compile error because here an object is expected, and I could find no example about this object. Further, I don't want to redefine typography, just ensure it gets applied.

I need a quick and easy way to apply colors, so I added the compatibility include (see this question about color variants), also because I have many Angular libraries just using mat-primary and similar classes for those variants. Yet, this does not seem to work e.g. for button background colors: I get only a different foreground for the button's labels.


As an example, here is my HTML in app.component.html:
<article>
  <div>
    <app-theme-toggle />
  </div>
  <hr />
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
      <!-- this has the expected typography -->
      <mat-card-title>Custom Theming with Toggle</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <!-- this appears in Times... -->
      <p>This is an example.</p>
      <div class="form-row">
        <!-- this has default background and only changes text foreground... -->
        <button type="button" mat-raised-button class="mat-primary">
          primary
        </button>
        <!-- as above... -->
        <button type="button" mat-raised-button class="mat-warn">
          warn
        </button>
      </div>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</article>


ADDITION: For colors, I played a bit with themes to avoid using legacy compatibility mixins which seem to introduce more issues. For instance here is an example using just a light theme: I added another theme for accent, and yet another one for error. Yet, this does not seem to work consistently: for instance, the "normal" color vs "accent" color are sometimes equal, like in checkboxes; and for icons, I have to force their color via explicit styles (see at the bottom, to be quicker I picked some of the variables I could see in the browser). Any suggestion is welcome, up-to-date documentation for M3 + Angular 19 seems lacking.
@use "@angular/material" as mat;

@include mat.core();

$light-theme: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      theme-type: light,
      primary: mat.$blue-palette,
    ),
  )
);

$accent-theme: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      theme-type: light,
      primary: mat.$violet-palette,
    ),
  )
);

$error-theme: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      theme-type: light,
      primary: mat.$red-palette,
    ),
  )
);

html {
  @include mat.all-component-themes($light-theme);
  & {
    color-scheme: light;
  }
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.mat-accent {
  @include mat.all-component-colors($accent-theme);
}

.mat-error, .mat-warn {
  @include mat.all-component-colors($error-theme);
}

mat-icon.mat-accent {
  color: var(--mdc-filled-text-field-focus-label-text-color) !important;
}
mat-icon.mat-error {
  color: var(--mat-form-field-error-focus-trailing-icon-color);
}

The corresponding HTML is:
<!-- icon buttons -->
<div class="form-row">
  <button type="button" mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <button type="button" mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon class="mat-accent">check_circle</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <button type="button" mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon class="mat-error">delete</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <!-- flat buttons -->
  <button type="button" mat-flat-button>normal</button>
  <button type="button" mat-flat-button class="mat-accent">accent</button>
  <button type="button" mat-flat-button class="mat-error">error</button>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <!-- icons -->
  <mat-checkbox>normal</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox class="mat-accent">accent</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox class="mat-error">error</mat-checkbox>
</div>


Not an answer to your questions, but a remark that I think it's not necessary to have two separate themes for dark mode and light mode. You can just have one single theme without the theme-type setting, and by setting the color-scheme property (which you already do), Angular Material automatically selects the correct dark/light colors. See the updated Theming guide
